# Typescript: Can I refer to type variables of a type variable?

Tags: typescript, generics

I have two generic types - `Client<T>` and `MockClient<T>`. I would like to describe a third generic type - `Mocked<C extends Client>` - which should be the specialization of `MockClient` corresponding to a given specialization of `Client`. For example:

```
type PersonClient = Client<Person>;

// the following two types should be equivalent
type MockPersonClient = Mocked<PersonClient>;
type MockPersonClient = MockClient<Person>;
```

In other words, I would like to declare a type like:

```
type Mocked<C extends Client<T>> = MockClient<T>;
```

Is it possible to do this in Typescript? If not, is there a proposal for it (I have no idea how this feature would be called), or is what I am describing ill-defined or fundamentally difficult to implement in a type system?

Comment: Can you add your definition for `Client<T>`?  If you can get a `T` value from some (possibly nested) property, then what you want is possible.

Comment: `Client` was just an illustration - the actual types I'm working with are rather complex; but I think I know what you're getting at. if `type Client<T> = {obj: T}` then I can use `type Mocked<C extends any> = MockClient<C['obj']>` (I did not think of this this!). However, my types are not like that - I can get at `T` only through method calls. Is there a way to express the return value of an indexed type? It also appears that I can't "cheat" by declaring a superfluous private property, it only works for me if it's public.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is fairly well-defined, but not currently available in TypeScript (as of v2.5).  One feature which would get you there is [type-level function application](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/17961) or the more general [extended `typeof` operator](https://github.com/microsoft/typescript/issues/6606).  I'm not sure when, if ever, these features will make it into TypeScript.

There are workarounds.  One that I've used, which you figured out from my comment, is to augment your `Client<T>` type with a superfluous/phantom property of type `T`.  Assuming `Client<T>` is a class, you could do something like:

```
class Client<T> {
   // phantom property
   _clientType: T = void 0 as any;

   // rest of class definition
} 
type Mocked<C extends Client<{}>> = MockClient<C['_clientType']>
```

Yes, it has to be a public property, but you can just give it a name that indicates it is for internal use (leading underscore).  At runtime it will just be undefined and no user of `Client` needs to pay attention to it.  (It's a little more complicated if `Client` is an interface you want to create an instance from an object literal, because TypeScript will complain that there's no `_clientType` property.)

It's up to you if it's worth doing that to your class. Other folks may well have different workarounds to suggest.  Good luck!